# How to make uppercase all files and folder on a directory?

Tags: windows-7, file-management, cmd.exe, batch-rename

How does one rename all folders and files in a folder into UPPERCASE?
 (if it is possible in its subfolders too)

I have this code, but it converts only files, not folders.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

pushd %currentfolder%

for %%f in (*) do (
   set "filename=%%~f"

   for %%A in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
      set "filename=!filename:%%A=%%A!"
   )
   ren "%%f" "!filename!" >nul 2>&1
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Does it have to be done via batch? Not that it can't, but there are just so many easier ways via third-party utils.

Answer (score 0):

### Non-recursive solution.

I don't know `cmd.exe`, so I can't fix your script, but if you have Python installed, you can use this script (which should work on all OSes):

```
import os

files = os.listdir('.')
for f in files:
    newname = f.upper()
    if newname == f:
        continue
    if newname in files:
        print( "error: %s already exists" % newname )
    os.rename(f, newname)
```

Just save it as `upcase_files_folders.py` and then run `python upcase_files_folders.py` in the directory whose files you wants to rename.

---

### Update: Recursive solution.

Sorry, I just realized you wanted a recursive solution.

The following script will walk the subdirectory tree, recording the files and subdirectories to be renamed on a stack. Then it pops the files/subdirectories from the stack one by one and upcases them.

(A two-stage solution is best, to avoid renaming directories in the middle of the traversal. Trying to do it all at once is going to be error-prone and fragile.)

Also, it's probably best to keep a log of the changes in case you run the script in error. This script will record all renames in `.upcase_files_folders.log`.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os

with open('.upcase_files_folders.log','a') as logfile:
    renames = []
    for d, subdirs, fs in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        for x in fs + subdirs:
            oldname = os.path.join(d, x)
            newname = os.path.join(d, x.upper())
            if x == '.upcase_files_folders.log' or newname == oldname:
                continue
    for (oldname, newname) in reversed(renames):
        os.rename(oldname, newname)
        print( "renamed:  %s  -->  %s" % (repr(oldname), repr(newname)), file = logfile )
```